# JSON Swift login error EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, json, swift, authentication, breakpoints

I am trying access my API to login and get information from there, always I get `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`, the information already get to my project but when go to home app always crash and show `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`

This my API http://elvbitstudio.azurewebsites.net/pickmeup/signin_process.php

This my code when access my API

```
var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
        NSLog("PostData: %@", post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://elvbitstudio.azurewebsites.net/pickmeup/signin_process.php")
        //var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin2.php")
        NSLog("url: %@",url);
        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        var postLength:NSString = String (postData.length)

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue( postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var responseError: NSError?
        var response : NSURLResponse?

        var urlData:NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error: &responseError)
```

and this my JSON Parse

```
var responseData:NSString = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData)
                var error:NSError?
                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:&error) as NSDictionary

                let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("Success") as NSInteger
```

I was wondering what would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simplify your code:

```
var url = "http://elvbitstudio.azurewebsites.net/pickmeup/signin_process.php"
var dataContent = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)!
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataContent, 
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
println(json["status"]!)
```

This works well for me.